# Autofiltering records in grid in asp.net according to keywords

Tags: c#, asp.net, grid

I want to search some items in a grid in asp.net C#. While i search for the records that I want to I don't want to hit the search button and then the grid will get filtered. I want that the grid should get filtered with the records that match the keyword that I am entering. I guess this can be done using html5 or j query. I am not able to exactly phrase my search for google.

Pleas help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So your looking for something similar to autocomplete by the sound of things? Try a google search of 'asp.net autocomplete search' if this is the case

Comment: @JamieHennerley : Not autocomplete. I dont want the records to get filtered in the search textbox. If I enter " abcd " in the search text box, I should be able to see all records having abcd as substring in it and these items are in grid. They are getting filtered in grid. I have a link for the same. I will post it you would like to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [dataTables](https://datatables.net/) we use it a lot for the custom filtering & sorting and it's a doddle to use

Comment: Yes. This is what I require. Where can I get code and explanation of the code for this.? How I can apply it to my asp.net gridview.?

Comment: You hook into it on the client side using javascript. As your gridviwe renders a table all you need to do is $('#MyTableId').dataTable()

Comment: $('#MyTableID') will here have my gridviews id.? Am I right.?

Comment: yep, if you inspect the output html, find the <table id="xxxxxxx"> element and use whatever appears in it's id attribute in the jquery selector

Comment: Please tell em If I am writing the code correctly, Following is my code
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $('#grdcity').dataTable()
    </script>